# peer-to-peer epoll clients and deadlock

Tags: networking, tcp, nonblocking, epoll

Suppose a peer-to-peer program uses `epoll` to perform asynchronous TCP reads from and writes to multiple peers. Naturally, this means that every file descriptor is set to nonblocking to allow `epoll_wait` to be called and for multiple sockets to be checked.

However, there is a potential issue. Suppose there are two peers: **A** and **B**. **A** tries to write a message to **B**, but **B** is congested or something and so the call to `write` returns -1 with `errno` set to `EAGAIN`. At this point, **A** goes to sleep on the call to `epoll_wait`.

But note that **B** is already stuck on its own call to `epoll_wait`. If **B** is never notified about **A**'s failed attempt to send it a message, then **B** will never wake up and try to perform a read on **A**'s socket, and the entire thing will deadlock. So my question is, is **B** guaranteed be notified that **A** is attempting to send it a message, even if **A** gives up on the original `write` call and goes to sleep?

Even if the answer to the above is "yes", is it possible for a system like this to deadlock indefinitely because of application-layer desynchronization? i.e. **A** tries to write to **B** but fails, so it goes to sleep. Then **B** wakes up and tries to read from **A**, but fails because **A** went to sleep. etc.

Comment: I'm essentially asking whether `epoll` will eventually register that an attempt was made to write to one of its file descriptors, even though the application that performed the write call stopped doing so.

Comment: I don't follow your example. Are you talking about a scenario where both A and B are waiting for the other to read some data before they'll make forward progress? If so, whatever protocol they're using is broken. Typically, you are required to continue reading even if you cannot write to avoid precisely this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any protocol that had a possible state where both sides are permitted to wait for the other side to read before they read would be a fundamentally broken protocol. For peer-to-peer protocols, typically each end is prohibited from delaying reads just because it cannot write.

On the implementation side, typically every call to `epoll_wait` (or the equivalent way you discover ready I/O) checks for input on all descriptors the program is using. Reading is *never* deferred unless the application has unprocessed data that it has already read and it stops deferring as soon as that data is processed. Waiting for network activity before reading is generally a very bad idea.

This is why typical protocol-neutral TCP proxies use two processes or two threads. You can't just read from A and then go do a blocking write to B because you don't know if B is required to read before it writes.

This is also why calling `recv` with `MSG_WAITALL` is almost always a bad idea. The other end might be waiting for you to receive the bytes it has already sent before it sends any more. No protocol can allow one side to wait for all the bytes to be sent before reading any of them if it also allows the other side to wait until some bytes have been read before sending the rest of them!

Comment: I'm not sure we're thinking of the same things, or perhaps I'm not seeing the connection. I want to create a single thread that relies on `epoll_wait` to check to see if any clients are ready for reading _or_ writing. If so, the thread will call read or write wherever applicable. This is a symmetric arrangement.

You state that a nonblocking read is almost always a bad idea. I'm not sure what you mean, since if you can at least guarantee that the sending application is performing a blocking write (though it doesn't in this case), you should be able to rely on nonblocking reads with `epoll`.

Comment: If you do a non-blocking read and the other side does too, then you are each waiting until the other side writes before you write. That's potential deadlock. But so long as you are always trying to write when you have data the other side might be waiting for and always trying to read except when you have unprocessed read data, deadlock is not possible.

Comment: So my understanding of the problem was that you can't generally assume the process on the other end is calling `read` at the very moment you perform a nonblocking `write`. So I assume a nonblocking `write` will fail in that case, unless TCP allows for a successful `write` even before the receiving process performs a `read` call. If the latter is true, and the receiving process will get notified by `epoll_wait` whenever there is a pending message to be read on the TCP stack, then I think that should also resolve any perceived problems.

Is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: To clarify, there isn't any real back-and-forth between processes. What a given process writes to a socket has no relation to whatever it receives from the same socket. So at the very least I think it's safe to say that no one is "waiting until the other side writes before [writing]", or waiting until the other side reads before reading.

Comment: @Navneeth A TCP non-blocking write will succeed if the data was successfully written to the TCP layer. The implementation will support some number of bytes to be "in flight" between the sender and the recipient before it applies back pressure to the writer.